# JavaScript APi google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть карта на ней есть функция которая отображает имя или еще что-то .Но чтоб отобразилось окно маркера , надо на него нажжать .Можно сделать как то авто показ окна чтоб он всегда показывал

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: вызови `infowindow.open(map, marker);` не по клику - и покажется

Comment: Да сработало .Убрал показ окна со слушателя )Спасибо